# Why changes on layout files of moodle are reflecting on browser so late

Tags: javascript, node.js, moodle, browser-sync

I am doing experiment by using browser-sync for developing moodle theme. After inserted the **css** by `<link />` tag into layout pages, I could change the style(eg:-color) and layout(columns3.php) of moodle theme in browser without reload.

Well the changes on **css** are reflecting near about 2 seconds in browser. But the reflect of changes on **layout**(tweak some html code in columns3.php) is reflecting very delay in browser.

Why layout changes is reflecting so late in browser? I am observing the moodle theme layout and css by command

```
browser-sync start --proxy "http://localhost/moodle/" --files "theme/clean/layout/*.php, theme/clean/style/*.css"
```

Is there any way through which I can increase the reflecting speed when I change on layout file.

**Updated :**
I have enabled the `Theme designer mode`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago. My solution was to turn on the "Theme designer mode" in HOME -> SITE ADMINISTRATION -> APPEARANCE -> THEMES -> THEME SETTINGS.

Comment: Already enabled the `Theme designer mode`,  but no any effect in delay time.

Comment: No any effect after purge all cache.,,(:

Answer (score 0):

I have found Moodle does cache some assets such as CSS files included outside the theme. Try running purge caches (/admin/cli/purge_caches.php) and see if this speeds things up.